# I’d like to modify a firmware file of Bluetooth module (HC-05)

Tags: bluetooth, firmware

I am working on the LMP layer of Bluetooth

What I’d like to do is modifying implementation of link manager protocol (LMP) to control LMP packet

According to a specification of Bluetooth, LMP is usually implemented in a firmware of Bluetooth module.

I was able to extract firmware from HC-05 module and re-flash the firmware

There are many sites that explain how to extract firmware from Bluetooth module with blue suite   [reference site](http://byron76.blogspot.kr/2011/09/upgrade-your-bluetooth-module.html)

Following picture is the hexadecimal view of Extracted firmware file.

[image]

As you can see, extracted file is not a binary file

I have to transform the firmware file to binary file for analyzing instruction with IDA pro

After I transformed the firmware file to binary, I can see firmware-like file format.

Here is the firmware file that I transformed to binary format

[Firmware file link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5L-0MoH_v7fYTQ4QkRUR1pYNzA)

This is what I've done so far

---

Here is my question.

1. What is the CPU architecture of HC-05? ( I need to indicate the
   architecture of firmware for disassembling instruction code)
2. Is there source code version of Bluetooth firmware?
3. Do you have any tips for analyzing the firmware file to modify specific functionality?

Thank you

Comment: Modifying the firmware this way most likely isnt going to work. A quick search turns up the HC-0X modules are CSR's BlueCore 04 modules, running on some kind of 16it RISC mcu. IDA's list of supported processors is long, but 90% is 32/64bit so this is going to be your first problem.

Secondly, any sane firmware developer will have used a checksum-/hash- verification of the firmware image, which might or might not be inside the programmable data area, and might or might not use private implementations of CRC etc making things even harder.

Comment: Thanks for your comment markus-nm 11

It would be the best result if I could disassemble the firmware with IDA
But If not, I would like to disassemble the code my own by studying instruction set
that is the reason why I am looking for the specific architecture of HC-0X module. I strongly believe that bypassing the checksum validation is trivial 
When I was studying firmware of Samsung printer, they validated the checksum of firmware
But the checksum value was nothing but adding every 2 bytes of firmware.
Once I am able to analyze the firmware, maybe I can handle the checksum issue

Comment: radare2 supports CSR disassembly. Moreover, if you will catch bugs, we will happily fix them. If you want to write an assembler by yourself, you can do this in C or Python as a plugin to RAsm: https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/plugins/plugins.html